# Zoomsounds: Load new file into div via data-source attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a javascript audio player named ZoomSounds. It creates divs of a circular play button and loads content into them like this:

`<div id="ap3" class="audioplayer-tobe skin-minimal"
                         style="position:absolute; width:100px;"
                         data-type="normal" data-source="sounds/edge.mp3"></div>`

What I'd like to do is have other files on the page and load them into the same div (ap3) through clicking their links. ZoomSounds doesn't seem to have any support, and it seems a waste of a nice little plugin. Is there a simple way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a paid plugin. You can ask the plugin author for help if you have purchased it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on what this plugin is doing with the data attributes and when, but if you just want to replace the `div#ap3`'s data attributes you can use jQuery.

So let's say you have another file referenced in an anchor tag like so:

```
<a class="replace1" href="sounds/replacement.mp3">The Replacement MP3</a>
```

You can grab that href and replace the div#ap3 data-source attribute with it like so:

```
(function($) {
    $("a.replace1").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var hrefReplacement = $(this).attr('href');
        $("div#ap3").data("source",hrefReplacement);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice. To my disappointment and irritation the author does not respond to support queries. The fix does not work, but perhaps there is something deeper in the code blocking the change: http://keneckert.com/test/ If you see something in this please do write, and otherwise thanks again.